# Increasing file indexing on OnStartupTriggeringPolicy in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

While rotating the file on OnStartupTriggeringPolicy in log4j2, 7 times the files is getting created with indexing 1,2,3 to 7 as shown below. After that it is over writing to the first one.

```
packs-03-29-2017-1.zip 
packs-03-29-2017-2.zip 
packs-03-29-2017-3.zip 
packs-03-29-2017-4.zip 
packs-03-29-2017-5.zip 
packs-03-29-2017-6.zip 
packs-03-29-2017-7.zip
```

Can someone tell me how to increase the number of file indexing in log4j2.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using the [DefaultRolloverStrategy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/DefaultRolloverStrategy.html) you can simply increase your "max" to the desired value within your configuration file.

See also:

[Log4j2 Manual: Rollover Strategies](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RolloverStrategies)